# Making headers from DLL exports

Tags: dll, header, export, dllexport

Is there a tool to extract/generate .h headers for DLL exports given only the DLL? Manually typing them is proving a pain in the backside...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible in case of generic C Dll. C procedure symbols have no type information *mangled in*.

dumpbin can list the procedure names, but you cannot deduce the return types, the number of parameters, e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with EFraim but maybe you have some extra, additional info, about the dll that you can use. http://www.dependencywalker.com/ lists all the functions that are exported by that module and could perhaps give you a clue depending on the dll.